# Como ordenar por una segunda condicion un array de objetos que tengan los mismos valores{javascript .sort()}

Tags: javascript, ordenamiento, ordenar

Estoy haciendo una tabla de posiciones de futbol en la cual en caso de empatar en puntos, quiero que el que tenga una mayor diferencia de goles pueda estar primero.

Entiendo que para ordenar por puntos seria lo siguiente

```
arrayDeEquipos.sort((a,b) => b.pts - a.pts)
```

sin embargo no se como agregarle esta segunda condicion.

arrayDeEquipos contiene las propiedades pts como tambien dif ya con valores

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicas los valores por un número grande y sumas la diferencia de goles

```js
const arrayDeEquipos =[
{ pts: 2, dif:2 },
{ pts: 2, dif:4 },
{ pts: 2, dif:5 },
{ pts: 2, dif:2 },
{ pts: 8, dif:1 },
{ pts: 2, dif:9 },
{ pts: 3, dif:2 },
];


let res = arrayDeEquipos.sort((a,b) => (b.pts * 1000 + b.dif) - (a.pts * 1000 + a.dif) );

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente lo que hace sort es retornar -1 si se quieres que `a` vaya primero, 0 si se quedan en esa posicion, o +1 si se quiere que `a` vaya despues.

Entonces puedes cambiar tu sort por algo así:

```js
const arrayDeEquipos =[
  { pts: 2, gf:2, gc: 1 }, //gf = goles a favor, gc = goles en contra
  { pts: 2, gf:5, gc: 0 },
  { pts: 2, gf:2, gc: 0 },
  { pts: 2, gf:3, gc: 1 },
  { pts: 8, gf:4, gc: 4 },
  { pts: 2, gf:2, gc: 8 },
  { pts: 3, gf:2, gc: 1 },
];
arrayDeEquipos.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.pts !== b.pts){ //Si los puntos son diferentes, se retorna el mayor primero
    return b.pts - a.pts;
  } else { //Los puntos son iguales, retornas el que tenga mas goles de diferencia
    const gda = a.gf - a.gc; //Goles de diferencia de a
    const gdb = b.gf - b.gc; //Goles de diferencia de b

    return gdb - gda;
  }
})

console.log(arrayDeEquipos);
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias por las respuestas, la solucion mas simple que se me ocurrio y que funciona fue agregarle otro .sort() luego de haberlo hecho una vez, de forma que quedo asi.

```
arrayEquipos.sort((a,b) => b.pts - a.pts).sort((a,b) => b.dif - a.dif)
```

Comment: Hola, esa solucion no funciona (quizas en tus datos actuales te funcione por casualidad), pero el ultimo sort ignora completamente el sort anterior, por lo tanto podría un elemento al inicio terminar en ultima posicion (cosa que según tus necesidades no funcionaría). Por ejemplo: `console.log([{pts:3, dif:4}, {pts:2, dif: 8}].sort((a,b) => b.pts - a.pts).sort((a,b) => b.dif - a.dif))`. Debería mostrarlos en el mismo orden, pero muestra el de 2 puntos primero

Comment: efectivamente tenias razon! no funciona